# How do you load video from an array in table detail view when the user clicks on the cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have loaded a table view with NSArray data. Now, I want to play a video in a detail view. The video played depends on what cell the user clicks.

How do I test the cell clicked and load a video from the array based on that?

I am using Xcode 5 for iOS 7.

Here is my ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "VideoDetailViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray * titlearray;
    NSMutableArray * arrayVidSrc;

}
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mytableview;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //sets delegate methods of table view
    self.mytableview.delegate=self;
    self.mytableview.dataSource=self;

    //assigns values to objects in array's
    titlearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"intro", @"skating",nil];

    arrayVidSrc = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Step1-Intro.mp4", @"Step2-Skating.mp4", nil];
}

// returns one section in the table
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

//counts the items in the title array
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [titlearray count];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"vidCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath: indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text  = [titlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetailsSeg"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexpath =nil;
        NSString *titlestring =nil;

        indexpath = [mytableview indexPathForSelectedRow];
        titlestring = [titlearray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

        NSURL * movieURL = [arrayVidSrc objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
        MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
        [[player view] setFrame: [self.view bounds]];
        [self.view addSubview: [player view]];
        [player play];

        [[segue destinationViewController] setTitlecontents:titlestring];
    }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

And here is my ViewController.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

    //allows us to use the delegate methods of table view
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>  

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mytableview;



    @end
```

I have a custom view controller class VideoDetailViewController.m:

```
#import "VideoDetailViewController.h"

@interface VideoDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation VideoDetailViewController

@synthesize arrayVidSrc = _arrayVidSrc;
@synthesize titlelabel;
@synthesize navBar;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.titlelabel.text = self.titlecontents;
    self.navBar.title = self.titlecontents;




    //video load from array
   // NSURL * movieURL = [_arrayVidSrc objectAtIndex:NSIndexPath.row];

    //Play the movie now
    /*MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];
    playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [playercontroller.moviePlayer play];
    playercontroller = nil;*/


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

and the .h file that goes with it:

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface VideoDetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navBar;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *selectedRow;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * titlecontents;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel * titlelabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *arrayVidSrc;


@end
```

Comment: What is your exact question? What are the exact problems that you are encountering? Do your code currently works? If not, which error do you get?

Comment: Thanks for responding, Paul. My code works perfectly. I need to know how to take it to the next level. Let me try to be more precise. I want to call a specific video from an array that corresponds to the data in the cells array. (The video called depends on what cell the user chooses.) Then, I want to display it in a view view controller.  I know it's possible to do this in story board by hard coding each cell to a view. But that seems like a clunky way to develop. I will have 15+ videos. I don't want 15 view controllers. I want one controller dynamically populated with a video from an array.

Comment: UPDATE: I have the segue to the detail view controller working. How do I load the videos into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the method `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`.  The sender is the cell that was clicked.  You can then call something like `[self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender]` to get the cell address and use the row of the returned index path to pick the video out of your array.

The new view controller that will be shown when the segue finishes is available within the `prepareForSegue::` method  as `[segue destinationViewController]` and you can pass it whatever it will need.

Comment: You're awesome. I did that. But, now I have an error that I cannot explain. Help? SEE EDITED CODE ABOVE

Comment: the error is in the viewcontroller.m file

//this line is throwing an error
indexpath = [mytableview indexPathforSelectedRow];

Comment: Here's the error: no visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'indexPathforSelectedRow]'

Comment: OMG! One letter! THanks!!

Comment: Phillip, why does it now go to some strange screen that says:
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}

Comment: Because something caused an exception that wasn't caught, so it drops you at the top level of your app.  There should be something useful printed in the debug console window.  If not, go to the breakpoint navigator and set a break on Objective-C exceptions.  With that set, it should show a stack trace that matches the error instead of what you're currently seeing.

Comment: all I get is this:
argc int 1 1
argv char ** 0x7fff5fbfed10 0x00007fff5fbfed10
*argv char * "/Users/sherrykhobbs/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Applications/7CAC9992-224B-4137-8E7A-B0971DC27FC9/MSC_V1.app/MSC_V1" 0x00007fff5fbfef68
**argv char '/' '/'

Comment: I don't get anythign useful. libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw:
0x101999966:  pushq  %rbp

Comment: If you have the breakpoint set, it should stop with a stack trace in the debug navigator (left side view).  If you type the command 'bt' in the debug console, it should show the same trace in a form that you can copy and paste.

Comment: I am too new at this to understand that. :/ I did try.

Comment: I found the error. It was an outlet to an old piece of code. I deleted it and reconnected it to the right one.

Comment: Will someone help me get to the next step?

Comment: Nothing. Sorry. I just noticed it was unchecked.